# Casting a Column in order to divide it by a percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
USE DNTEMP
UPDATE enchanttable_95_temp
SET _State1Value = CAST(CAST(_State1Value AS NUMERIC(18, 2)) AS NVARCHAR(50))/1.10;
```

I've written the following query above in order to slice a table up according to a percentage, but I've been met with the following error. I've tried researching these online but I cannot seem to comprehend this certain situation.

I've tried converting to float, cast, round function you name it.

> [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: Why do you `CAST(... AS NVARCHAR(50))` before division?

Comment: The error message tells you that `_State1Value` contains a string that cannot be converted to a number... "foobar", "1,234.56" etc

Answer (score 2):

You have some values that are not numbers.  I would recommend `TRY_CONVERT()`:

```
UPDATE enchanttable_95_temp
    SET _State1Value = TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), _State1Value) / 1.10;
```

SQL Server will automatically convert the result back to a string, if you have `_State1Value` as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little sample to solve your issue

```
CREATE TABLE enchanttable_95_temp
(
  _State1Value NVARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO enchanttable_95_temp (_State1Value) VALUES
(N'10000'),
(N'FooBar');

SELECT _State1Value
FROM enchanttable_95_temp;

UPDATE enchanttable_95_temp
SET _State1Value = COALESCE(
                            CAST(TRY_CAST(_State1Value AS NUMERIC(18, 2) ) / 1.10 AS NVARCHAR(50)),
                            _State1Value
                           );

SELECT _State1Value
FROM enchanttable_95_temp;
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3df744c4fef4edb46c7781d4fe26d0d3)**</kbd>

Or even by filtering the data as

```
UPDATE enchanttable_95_temp
SET _State1Value = CAST(_State1Value AS NUMERIC(18,2)) / 1.10
                 -- SQL Server will cast the data to NVARCHAR here
WHERE _State1Value NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%';
```